# Set a Spring Boot property using a value from JNDI

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I put a string stored in JNDI to Spring Boot properties?

A bit more details:
I get my `DataSource` from JNDI using this property in `application.properties`:
`spring.datasource.jndi-name=my_data_source_jndi_name`. Currently, the DB schema is hard coded in `application.properties` in the following way: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema`. There is a JNDI record that containd the DB schema name. How can I get the schema from JNDI too?

Comment: Just add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` as property to JNDI and it will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Spring will resolve properties from JNDI and so you can therefore parameterise it in various ways. You can bypass the properties file and use the `@Value()` annotation directly in Java config

```
@Value("my.property.in.jndi")
private String schema;
```

*or* you can do as below in the properties file:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${my.property.in.jndi}`

Comment: You don't need this construct just add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` as a JNDI property. As JNDI as enabled a `JndiPropertySource` will be registered and property resolution from JNDI will be enabled. Where the properties come from doesn't matter (could be file, jndi or even DB if you have a `PropertySource` for that).